# How Can I Use VBA To Access A WebPage (IHTMLDocument?)

Tags: internet-explorer, vba, excel, automation

Using the following code, I can open up an Internet Explorer window and navigate to the website. I would like to go further by being able to have a code click through one of the links (such as "Boxing/UFC").

```
Sub Run()   
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With IE
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate2 "http://www.bet365.com"
    Do Until .ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
    .Quit
End With
```

Because that link leads to a Javascript `onclick` event (`onclick="gS(1020,9);return false;"`) can you suggest code I could use that would enable VBA to click through that link without the user's interference once the VBA macro is run?

Answer (score 2):

In Internet Explorer, you can simply click a link via the DOM API.

Retrieve the DOM node (the `A`) you are interested in, and call `click()` on it. This will also fire all associated event handlers.

---

EDIT: In your case, with VBA, do something like this (untested, I don't have VBA here)

```
Dim sideNav As IHTMLElement 
Dim navLinks As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim currLink As IHTMLElement

Set sideNav = IE.document.getElementByID("sln")
Set navLinks = sideNav.all.tags("A")

For Each currLink In navLinks
  If Trim(currLink.innerText) = "Boxing/UFC" Then
    currLink.Click
  End If
Next currLink
```

Comment: Hi Tomalak, please forgive me I am a noob when it comes to using VBA and the DOM node (though I have researched this and it has been mentioned.)  Would you be able to elaborate more on this please?  What codes would I use ?

Comment: @Jason see edit. I have no way to test it right now. It should still give you an idea of what to do. Both extensive use of the VBA debugger and referring to [the documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is strongly advised

Comment: Hi Tomalak, thanks for the example code.  I set a watch and it appears that the SideNav code does not retrieve a value so the NavLinks has nothing to tag.  I am trying to refer to the MSDN documentation as well so I will continue at this but if you have any other suggestions that would be great.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would need to query the html document, and retrieve the collection. Once you retrieve the collection you would need to iterate through the elements and click it.

I am pasting a snippet of the code here ([click here for the entire code](http://kmdarshan.com/blog/?p=3834)). This is in c++, but i am assuming it must be the same for VB too.

```
            IHTMLElementCollection *spCollectEmbed;
            spDocument->get_links(&spCollectEmbed);
            if(spCollectEmbed)
            {
            // get all the links
            long lLen;
            spCollectEmbed->get_length(&lLen);
            for (long i = 0; i < lLen; i++)
            {
                IDispatch *ppvdispOption;
                IHTMLElement *interfaceHTMLElement;
                VARIANT index;
                index.vt = VT_I4;
                index.lVal = i;

        // get the item from the document
                HRESULT hResult = spCollectEmbed->item(index, index, &ppvdispOption);
                if(SUCCEEDED(hResult))
                {
        // query for the element
        hResult = ppvdispOption->QueryInterface( IID_IHTMLElement,
        (void **) &interfaceHTMLElement);
        if(SUCCEEDED(hResult))
        {
        BSTR innerhtml;
        interfaceHTMLElement->get_innerHTML(&innerhtml);
        // click the links
        interfaceHTMLElement->click();
        Sleep(2000);
        }
```